# ERROR 1045 (28000) with comcast

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to link my local mysql server to aws mysql database instance. I ran the following command:

```
mysql -h instance.cvxqy8tbi2bk.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u root -p
```

I'm getting the following error. I searched on internet and I found solutions with respect to `root@localhost`.

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'c-98-239-128-245.hsd1.pa.comcast.net' (using password: YES)

Any pointers for this ?

Thanks

Comment: External root login may be disabled. Try creating an additional user for external connections.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I created an external user with '%' hostname. Now I am getting the following error : ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'instance.cvxqy8tbi2bk.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110). I tried commenting the #bind-address  = localhost but no solution. Any pointers for this ?